# Why are my breakpoints not hit in CLion?

Tags: debugging, breakpoints, clion

I'm trying to debug an executable which has been created with CMake configuration

```
SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
```

However, CLion does not hit any breakpoints. What could be the problem?

Comment: Thanks, your question solved my problem, adding `SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)` worked for me.

Comment: same here! thanks!

Comment: I have tried every one of these solutions and none of them works. My program just doesn't stop on my breakpoints. It is almost making it pointless to use Clion, which is sad because I like JetBrains software for every other kind of programming I do.

Comment: My issue seems to be connected to this problem with lldb on catalina: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/3829. But this is dealing with the issue on vscode. Don't know how to reproduce the solution with clion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it has turned out, the executable was compiled with following CMake options (further down in the script):

```
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "-D_DEBUG")
```

This was breaking debug functionality for CLion (it was also breaking most of the debug functionality of `gdb`)

Comment: If you need to append your own debug flags, this is the fix::  set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG} -D_DEBUG")

Comment: @mstrap If this is the problem, what is the fix? just delete it?

Answer (score 15):

I had the same issue today. I figured out that the configuration for the project was not set to `Debug`. After setting the configuration to `Debug` all the breakpoints are hit.

Please ensure that you have following configuration:

- Select the MenuItem `Run/EditConfigurations`
- Select the right `Target`
- Select `Debug` as `Configuration`

Now the breakpoints should be hit.

Comment: In configuration I dnt see Debug as an option. Can you please suggest how to add debug as an option in configuration.

Comment: @Vishal You can find the steps in [Creating and Editing Run/Debug Configurations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html)

Comment: CLion documentation is very obscure. I am facing the same problem and am preparing for a long trip to understand the philosophy of configurations, relation with CMake and debuger.

Answer (score 10):

In case this helps someone else, it turned out that my (somewhat embarrassing) issue was that I was hitting `Run` instead of `Debug`. So in the Run menu don't use the play icon, instead choose the cute bug icon instead. Choosing Run was causing it to automatically build the non-debug build so breakpoints wouldn't work. Once I started choosing the bug icon, the breakpoints worked like a charm.

Comment: Yeaaah. that would be me.  This is what happens when you don't use a Big Damn UI for a coupe of months.  You forget  how the cutesy buttons work, exactly ;)

Answer (score 4):

In my case my CMake option CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE was already set to DEBUG on CMake Settings. However, it was the command set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release) in the CMakeLists.txt, which was merged by git pull and overrode the CMake Settings while execution. I could not figure out earlier as CMake Debug console was showing -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug

When I changed it to set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug) breakpoints were hit again.

Answer (score 4):

In case this helps someone else:

In my case I had to set the `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` option to `Debug` explicitly in Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> CMake

[image: My case]

Comment: I had to do this too, why is that? The Build type should already define this...

Answer (score 3):

I also had the same Problem. Since 2016.3 CLion changed the CMake workflow so that only one configuration is allowed at one time [clion new workflow](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2016/10/clion-2016-3-eap-cmake-overload-resolution/)

The solution is File -> Settings -> Build, Excution, Deployment -> change the build configuration

Comment: In 2019.2 the path is slightly different:  File -> Settings -> Build, Excution, Deployment -> CMake

Answer (score 3):

I had a different issue that caused my breakpoints not to be hit.  I develop both embedded apps and native MacOS console apps with CLion.  For the embedded work, GDB needs to be set for your selected Preferences/Toolchains.

For debugging console apps LLDB needs to be selected in Preferences/Toolchains.  If it is left on GDB, my breakpoints don't work.  Set to LLDB here:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had a comma in my project path. Removing the comma fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Oh, man! Thank you so much! It resolved my problem. Your answer is one of the most underestimated!

Comment: Same issue for me. Anyone know why a comma breaks things?

Comment: When my project is in the`/tmp` directory, the breakpoint doesn't work, but when the project is in `~/CLionProjects` the breakpoint works, I spent a lot of time troubleshooting this problem, what's the reason behind it?

Comment: See [CPP-30773](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-30773/Breakpoints-do-not-take-effect-when-files-are-created-through-symbolic-link-directories)

Answer (score 1):

In 2019.3, it turns out to be CLion/Preference/Build,Execution,Deployment/CMake/Build type/Debug.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was with the `-ffile-prefix-map` flag. Once I removed it, everything worked fine.

See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-23159 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-15850

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I noticed that every time I click the debug option, the "Antimalware Service Executable" process starts. I created an exclusion for MinGW folder in windows Defender and it worked fine...

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Just like minecrawler said in github, if your os is linux, your should set：

file/Settings/Build,Execution,Deployment/Tllochains/Debugger from Bundled GEB or gdb to Bundled LLDB.

I tried and it worded！

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Linux / Ubuntu) the problem was somehow related to mounted directory.
The project was initially opened in CLion from `/media/username/ssd/repo/git/projectname`. The breakpoints were always disabled with message `No executable code is associated with this line`.

Then I opened the same project from a symlinked directory
`~/git` -> `/media/username/ssd/repo/git` and the breakpoints began to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to edit the file so that everything was compiled again instead of using cache.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem is forget to comment out optimize option `add_definitions(-O3)` in cmakelists. which let compiler go release.

Answer (score 0):

in the case of "the platform is currently not connected" of CLION for RUST, it turns out there is an authorization step which is not enabled on CLION 2022.2 version.

download the correct version solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had `target_link_options(app PRIVATE -s)` in my `CMakeLists.txt` which of course removed all necessary symbols ‍♂️

From the gcc docs at
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html

> -s       Remove all symbol table and relocation information from the executable.